# Observer does not work for recursive items

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, mobx-state-tree, mobx-react-lite

I'm really stuck with the problem. I have a nested menu. After click on the first menu level second level items shows up. After click on one of the children nothing happens. Looks like the observer don't work for deep levels items. I don't know if the "late" type could be a problem. Everything is described in the code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/mobx-state-tree-recursive-deep-menu-p7eqj

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that when you are using your recursive `TreeItem` component it is not actually `observer`. You wrapping it in `observer` only when exporting, but `TreeItem` inside `TreeItem` is regular component, not `observer` so it doesn't react to anything.

Basically you just need to move `observer` decorator:

```js
// Use `observer` right here straight away
const TreeItem = observer((props) => {
  const handleClick = () => {
    props.item.active ? props.item.deactivate() : props.item.activate();
  };

  const ItemChildren = ({ children }) => {
    return (
      <ul>
        {children.map((child) => (
          <TreeItem key={child.id} item={child} />
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <li onClick={handleClick}>{props.item.id}</li>
      {props.item.active && (
        <ItemChildren children={values(props.item.children)} />
      )}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
});

// Remove it from here
export default TreeItem;
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/httpsstackoverflowcomquestions67501643-i22vx?file=/src/components/TreeItem.jsx)